# Fresco : A question on Inner workings when using data uri for loading images/animations (webp/gif)

Tags: android, imageview, fresco, simpledraweeview

So, we are using Fresco in our android app and so far it has been great. There is one issue that we are seeing when we load an image of size `8000x4500`. We are seeing a Jank when that image is being loaded in the list on all devices and on some lower end devices, we are getting an OOM error (which is ok because we were testing on a 80$ device which is low on resources). Not sure if we are doing anything wrong or missing something.

In our app all images are encoded as `DataUri`s (conforms to RFC 2397) and we are loading the images using `setImageURI` method.

Now my question is, does the conversion of URI to bitmap inside Fresco happens on the same thread or does it happen in a background thread? I was trying to browse the code and understand it myself, but understanding the control flow wasn't straightforward. In particular, I couldn't figure out how the [`mTopLevelDrawable`](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/bbe21f260bba7057ddbe054de976c279e7a771f7/drawee/src/main/java/com/facebook/drawee/generic/GenericDraweeHierarchy.java#L258) is updated for `ImageRequest` of type `DataUri`.

Any help on understanding how it works, what could be done at the application level to prevent it would be great.

We are ok to set a maximum dimension to something like `1280` or the width of the window. Would that help reduce the decoding time?

Thanks in advance!

*Note : We deliberately choose a high resolution image to understand the limits of our product. For regular sized images, things are pretty smooth. For high resolution images, even on higher end devices like pixel 4, there is a jank.*